# Python - Reading different urls using urllib2 returned the same results?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to use Python `urllib2` to read some pages but for given different urls returned the same page.

The page is an inquiry for campsite availability for a given campground from recreation.gov. Since there might be a lot campsites in a campground, the last index in url tells the page how many campsites will be listed.

For example if `startIdx=0` the page lists out campsite 1~25, and if `startIdx=25` the page lists out campsite 26~50.

So I constructed some urls with different `startIdx` but after using `urllib2` to read the page, the returned html were all the same -- it seems somehow the `startIdx` in url was ignored.

In addition, if I manually open those urls in browser the pages look normal, but if I use `webbrowser.open` to open those urls the pages look weird.

The brief sample code duplicates the problem I'm having:

```
import urllib2

url1 = 'http://www.recreation.gov/campsiteCalendar.do?page=calendar&contractCode=NRSO&parkId=70928&calarvdate=03/11/2016&sitepage=true&startIdx=0'
url2 = 'http://www.recreation.gov/campsiteCalendar.do?page=calendar&contractCode=NRSO&parkId=70928&calarvdate=03/11/2016&sitepage=true&startIdx=25' 

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
request1 = urllib2.Request( url1, headers = hdr )
response1 = urllib2.urlopen( request1 )    
html1 = response1.read() 

request2 = urllib2.Request( url2, headers = hdr )
response2 = urllib2.urlopen( request2 )    
html2 = response2.read() 

In [1]:html1 == html2
Out[2]: True
```

I have no other knowledge about how things work in inquiries and PHP related stuff. So I'm curious why does `urllib2` behave like this. The Python version I'm using is 2.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The web page may change during runtime, whereas you are only requesting HTML. There is probably some JavaScript that changes the contents of the page based on the URL encoded information. If the content was loaded server-side with PHP, then it would be present with the request as the server changes the HTML before sending it. JavaScript will change the HTML after sending it.

In other words, a regular browser will change the HTML based on the URL using JavaScript. Your simple request will not do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Although the explanation you provide may shed some light on the issue - it is not sufficient as an answer to the question. Please consider using comments in cases such as this. There are also some issues with technical/factual accuracy of your answer- you really need to investigate the issue further yourself if you are to provide a meaningful answer. See [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Did you mean the HTML I requested contains all campsites info but browser  changes the way to display it based on the `startIdx` in URL? A bit of information I missed in my question is different `startIdx` returned the same page as `startIdx=0`.

Comment: @fengly20 The HTML you requested probably doesn't contain any information about the campsites. The data is probably loaded through JavaScript once the page is ready for it to load. What you are using won't load it at all.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla How was the question not answered? _I'm curious why does urllib2 behave like this._ I explained that it was not what urllib2 was doing, it is what it isn't doing.

Comment: @RitLew The HTML I requested contains campsites information as `startIdx=0`, no matter what `startidx` I set. That's why I thought `startidx` gets ignored when requesting using `urllib2` -- all different urls returned the same page as setting `startidx` to 0, which lists out first 25 campsites information. I also tried using package `requests` and got the same results. Thanks for your answer and reply.